# Generate executable jar with maven : class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, jms, executable-jar

I have a Spring JMS project managed via maven, I encounter the following issue when the deployment of the jar file (java -jar jarname.jar):

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'outgoingMessageEventListener' defined in
>   class path resource [deltaMessageListenerContainer.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'deltaBankMessageService' while setting bean
>   property 'deltaBankMessageService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in class
>   path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'messageOutDao' while setting bean property 'messageOutDao'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'messageOutDao' defined in class path
>   resource [data-access.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Could not instantiate bean class
>   [com.delta.jms.message.persistence.ibatis.SqlMapMessageOutDao]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapExecutor   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at com.delta.jms.server.bootstrap.Startup.main(Startup.java:26)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in
>   class path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'messageOutDao' while setting bean property 'messageOutDao';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageOutDao' defined in class path resource
>   [data-access.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.delta.jms.message.persistence.ibatis.SqlMapMessageOutDao]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapExecutor   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
>     ... 19 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageOutDao' defined in class path resource
>   [data-access.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.delta.jms.message.persistence.ibatis.SqlMapMessageOutDao]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapExecutor   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
>     ... 32 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.delta.jms.message.persistence.ibatis.SqlMapMessageOutDao]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapExecutor   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
>     ... 43 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapExecutor   at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport.(SqlMapClientDaoSupport.java:46)
>     at
>   com.delta.jms.message.persistence.ibatis.SqlMapMessageOutDao.(SqlMapMessageOutDao.java:23)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapExecutor   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 52 more

Thank you.

Mac

---

Thank you Ronald. I have this new error now :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'outgoingMessageEventListener' defined in
>   class path resource [deltaMessageListenerContainer.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'deltaBankMessageService' while setting bean
>   property 'deltaBankMessageService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in class
>   path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'jmsSender' while setting bean property 'jmsSender'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path resource
>   [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/JMSException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at com.delta.jms.server.bootstrap.Startup.main(Startup.java:26)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in
>   class path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'jmsSender' while setting bean property 'jmsSender'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path
>   resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/JMSException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
>     ... 19 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path resource
>   [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/JMSException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
>     ... 32 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/JMSException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/JMSException    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
>     ... 56 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.jms.JMSException    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 62 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you, Ronald and Yohannes, for your help! Actually, I did find the MAIN PROBLEM! I was making some dependencies in pom.xml as system and I put the absolute path of these jar files in  tag. When I package the project as an executable jar file it doesn't take those dependencies inside! So to avoid that, I uploaded these specific jars into a Nexus server (I have already one) and I declare them as scope compile in pom.xml, that's all! I overcame these "dependencies" errors but I've got another kind of errors!

Answer (score 3):

Looks You are missing some dependency jars. When I get such errors I always do

1. Search(Google) for the jar that contains the missing class, in your case com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapExecutor
2. add the jar into your maven pom.xml dependency

Notice also that, sometimes if you have two versions of the same jar somewhere in your class path might give you this issue. In this scnerio, you can turn on the verbose mode to see which version picked up during runtime

Comment: Thank you Yohannes for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you don't have `com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapExecutor` on your classpath. You're using maven as your build tool, so check your POM for dependencies.

I do not know which depenceny you actually need, but it should be something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronald, for your answer. I forget to tell you that I don't have this problem if I run the program from Eclipse! I don't know why when I run the jar instead, I got this error?!

Comment: A classpath in Eclipse consists of: The current Java Project and any Java Projects added to the classpath via the Java Build Path in the Properties of the current Project, or any Libraries in the build path. That's why it might run in Eclipse and not as an executable jar. You have to package all dependent jars into your jar.So, the question remains. Do you have included the missing dependency in your pom?

Comment: Thank you Ronald, I did add the new dependency as you told me, the old error had gone but Igot a new one above.

Comment: You're missing another dependency: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException`. Do as @Yohannes stated: search for the jar and add the missing dependency to your pom. You have to do that until you have resolved all your missing dependencies.

Comment: I want to thank you Ronald for your help!
Actually I did find the MAIN PROBLEM! I was making some dependencies in pom.xml as <scope>system</scope> and I put the absolute path of these jar files in <systemPath> tag. When I package the project as an executable jar file it doesn't take those dependencies inside! So to avoid that, I upload these specific jars into a Nexus server (I have already one) and I declare them as scope compile in pom.xml, that's all! I overcame these "dependencies" errors but I've got another kind of errors! Can I edit my post or just create a new one?